# Google dense_hash_map C++

Tags: c++, string, google-maps

So, I'm trying to implement a map that will have probably around 20,000 String, String pairs in C++.  Is it worth it to use Google Dense Hash Map?  I will be mainly checking the map for the pair and inserting it if not found.  I wont be making any deletions or alterations to the pairs.  If I should use dense hash map, how do I?  There is not much information online but I know I need a hash function.

EDIT: they are String to String pairs

Comment: Any particular reason why you would avoid STL map like structures?

Comment: Just trying to get the best performance.  Im using a std::map right now but I'm curious if I should switch to google dense hash map

Comment: U have `unordered_map` in C++11

Comment: @KaiserWilhelm Depends on your usage. You would need to run some benchmarks I guess. No need to add another dependency if you don't have too.

Comment: @Hauleth I dont see my work implementing C++11 anytime soon but thanks I look into this

Comment: @FailedDev What are the main advantages to google dense hash map? Is it overkill if I am just looking up and inserting?

Comment: @KaiserWilhelm: Though it is officially part of C++11, most C++03 implementations also had a `stdext::hashmap` (name varies) which is virtually the same as `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @KaiserWilhelm: According to [a random study](http://lrde.epita.fr/~charron/hashtable_performance.pdf), google's dense map outperforms boost's hashmap in virtually every category.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a hash map to be faster and have a bit of spare memory then go for it.

Google dense map is easy to install (`aptitude install libsparsehash-dev` [on Debian](http://packages.debian.org/jessie/libsparsehash-dev)) and it is header-only so you don't even need to link to another library. It is a fastest hash map around, but has higher memory requirements than other maps.

http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html benchmark has a good comparison of performance and memory profiles (here's the raw results of that benchmark from 2013-08-02: http://pastebin.com/jJL3rzWp).

Note, that for some loads a [b+tree](http://google-opensource.blogspot.ru/2013/01/c-containers-that-save-memory-and-time.html) can me more cache-friendly than a hash.